# Opening JSON UI screens from entities/blocks

Tags: gui, minecraft-modding, minecraft-bedrock-modding

I'm making a Bedrock Edition mod with JSON, and I want to be able to specifically open a JSON UI screen within events of a behavior pack or in a script.

```
"minecraft:on_interact": {
    ...
    "event": "open_gui_screen(ui/screens/screen1.json)"
}
```

I've looked through all of the documentation and the [Bedrock wiki](https://wiki.bedrock.dev), but it doesn't show much about opening a JSON UI menu through events on an entity or from the JavaScript code.